# MySQL Checksum differs but cannot find difference in table

Tags: mysql, mariadb, mariadb-10.4, checksum

I have two tables which are expected to be the same

```
CHECKSUM TABLE robot, tbd_robot #Doesn't match
```

All the column types (storage format) are the same, the engine and collation are also the same. The table DDLs are identical.

I tried running the intersect ([as mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950414/mysql-compare-differences-between-two-tables)):

```
SELECT  'robot' AS `set`, r.*
FROM    robot r
WHERE   ROW(r.col1, r.col2, …) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  col1, col2, ...
        FROM    tbd_robot
        )
UNION ALL
SELECT  'tbd_robot' AS `set`, t.*
FROM    tbd_robot t
WHERE   ROW(t.col1, t.col2, …) NOT IN
        (
        SELECT  col1, col2, ...
        FROM    robot
        )
```

Again, nothing differs nothing differs between the two table.

I tried running checksums column by column:

```
SELECT SUM(CRC32(yourColumnName)) AS anyAliasName FROM robot; #Redo for each column for each table
```

Again, nothing differs between the two table.

I also look at the data_length

```
SELECT DATA_LENGTH, INDEX_LENGTH, ENGINE, AUTO_INCREMENT, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_COLLATION
FROM information_schema.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' and TABLE_SCHEMA = 'robot' and TABLE_NAME = 'tbd_robot';
```

Again, DATA_LENGTH does not differ between the two table.

Why is my checksum different if I can't find anything different between the two tables?

Comment: Try the checksum in Percona toolkit.

Comment: Where both tables created on the same server version? Does the table have a primary key so the checksum order of rows is consistent?

Comment: @danblack same server version and yes it has a primary key. For full info, the DB had 20+ tables and they all matched except one.